# MySQL hang during "show collation" on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, collation

MySQL is hanging when I try to do `SHOW COLLATION` on my Amazon RDS instance.  I can use `SHOW COLLATION` fine with my local database, and other SQL commands work fine on my RDS instance. But Amazon `SHOW COLLATION` hangs every time.  Maybe I have too many collations?  I'd be perfectly happy just setting it to utf8 or Latin1 collation.

I'm using mysql(5.6.12) on a micro instance.

Any ideas on what I can do? Or how can I get more information on what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you found a solution to this but for us it seems to be related to the size of data leaving the VPC.

If you run a query with a small result set:

```
show collation like '%utf8_swedish%';
```

The result returns fine, but if you take away the like and get a large result set back it fails. We're still investigating the problem but not sure you found a solution.